# Creating an entry in Windows Event Viewer

Tags: c++, windows, manifest, event-viewer

I want to create a new entry under `Applications and Services Log` in `Windows Event Viewer` for my application. I used `ECManGEN` tool to generate the `manifest` and after doing the necessary steps linked it with my project. It works.. However, a folder is created with the provider name(MyTrial2 in below figure) and the channel comes under that folder. Is it possible to have only the channel without the folder?(As Internet Explorer, Microsoft Office Alerts, etc in the figure)

[image]

EDIT - Added the generated Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<instrumentationManifest xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events eventman.xsd" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events" xmlns:win="http://manifests.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/windows/events" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:trace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
    <instrumentation>
        <events>
      <provider name="MyTrial2" guid="{90DDCC4A-2F8A-4B57-85AF-5401E678708A}" symbol="MyTrial2" resourceFileName="E:\MyEventTrial\MyEventTrial\Debug\MyEventTrial.exe" messageFileName="E:\MyEventTrial\MyEventTrial\Debug\MyEventTrial.exe">
        <events>
          <event symbol="EvenEvent2" value="1" version="0" channel="TrialChannel2" level="win:Informational" message="$(string.MyTrial.event.1.message)">
          </event>
          <event symbol="OddEvent2" value="2" version="0" channel="TrialChannel2" level="win:Informational" message="$(string.MyTrial.event.2.message)">
          </event>
          <event symbol="ErrorEvent2" value="3" version="0" channel="TrialChannel2" level="win:Error" message="$(string.MyTrial.event.3.message)">
          </event>
        </events>
        <levels>
        </levels>
        <channels>
          <channel name="TrialChannel2" chid="TrialChannel2" symbol="TrialChannel2" type="Admin" enabled="true">
          </channel>
        </channels>
      </provider>
        </events>
    </instrumentation>
</instrumentationManifest>
```

Comment: Can you please post the config you used w/ ECManGen? Most likely you have specified MyTrial2/TrialChannel2 as a name used in the channel, which results in the folder.

Comment: @tmruss: didi you mean the .man file?

Comment: Correct - the manifest which specified all the options you used.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382741(v=vs.85).aspx

I would read the above doc, specifically the "remarks" section at the bottom. I don't have access to a windows comp right now to check it out further. It looks like microsoft wants to organize these into folders for providers with channels underneath. Keep in mind you can also import legacy channels, of which Application is a type of legacy channel - that may be how the other event logs that simply list a channel/log work. I can't verify that 100% though. good luck.

Comment: @tmruss: Ok ..Thankyou.. Let me check it :)